# Commit offset in kafka consumer in VB .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I have a case when consumer will be down then the offset should be used to check which message will be picked from where it left and not start from beginning. I have found many ways in other languages but I need the same in VB .net. How to implement offset in vb.net and commit?

Comment: If I understood your question, this is default Kafka behavior (consumers are **not** always started from the beginning), so what issues are you running into?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Commit` or `Close` on an [`IConsumer`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/_site/api/Confluent.Kafka.IConsumer-2.html) instance, it will commit its offsets (assuming auto commit is enabled for `Close`).

When the consumer is restarted for the same `GroupId` then those committed offsets will be used.